# Lubuntu 20_04 GUI does not start, only terminal

Tags: boot, 20.04, lubuntu, sddm

Lubuntu 20 04 boots either in a "text mode" and says `[ok]` for

```
Finished hold until boot process finishes up
Started OpenBSD Secure Shell Server
Finished Terminate Plymouth Boot Screen
```

Or it boots to a black screen.

Then nothing happens.

With Alt-F1 I can go to tty1
With Alt F7, it will not start in GUI. Instead I get back to the above message or black screen, but no gui

I use `/usr/bin/Sddm`, and starting it (service sddm start) does not work as user nor as root (Unit sddm.service is masked).

I do not have as commands `start` nor `startx`.

Usually when it works it boots to the `Sddm`.

But after a restart, the described behaviour comes up. I played with the path var, and /usr/bin is on the path. I compared `/etc/environment` to my path, and it seems ok.

The Lbuntu Logo with the 4 dots shows up shortly before finishing booting, but after one second disappears.

Any help?

Comment: With `dpkg-reconfigure sddm` I get: sddm ist kaputt oder nicht komplett installiert.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by going to the Boot Menu with `esc` and selecting Ubuntu. It then booted to `Sddm` and not text mode.

Another solution is to check the display manager with `cat/etc/X11/default-display-manager`.

Then make sure that `/usr/bin/sddm` is available. If not:

`apt install sddm`